# Loop over the data-set columns and calculate statistics in R

Tags: r

I am just starting with R and need help with looping over the data-set and calculating statistics.

I have two data-sets:

```
>head(windows)
W1
W1
W2
W2
W3
W4
W4
W5 
...

>head(values) # this is very large file (>20Gb)
Case1   Case2   Case3   Case4   ... 
   21      19      14      64
   14      24      48      13
   21      34      65      83
   45      53      25      63
   62      32      72      11
   24      75      12      66
   12      23      73      37
   45      23      56      74
   ...
```

**What I what to do:**

1. For every `Case` column in `values` join it with `windows` row by row;
   Should look something like this (`Case1`):

   `W1  21`
   `W1  14`
   `W2  21`
   `W2  45`
   `W3  62`
   `W4  24`
   `W4  12`
   `W5  45`
2. For every  joined `window` group, e.g.:

   - W1(Case1): 21,14
   - W2(Case1): 21,45
   - W3(Case1): 62
   - W4(Case1): 24,12
   - W5(Case1): 45
   - W1(Case2): 19,24

   Calculate mean (or median);

Perfect output would look like this:

```
    Case1   Case2   Case3   Case4
W1  17.50   21.50   mean    mean
W2  33.00   mean    mean    mean    
W3  62.00   mean    mean    mean
W4  18.00   mean    mean    mean
W5  45.00   mean    mean    mean
```

**Pseudo code might be:**

```
For cases in values
   join row by row with windows
   For every window
     Calculate mean
   end
end
```

NB: I have tried joining `windows` with `values` using `rbind`,`merge`,`data.frame`, but data-sets are too large and process gets killed.

Comment: Have a look on the package "data.table". 
http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/data.table.pdf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have a considerably large data file, I think there are two good options to do it, either using `data.table` or `dplyr`. So here's how you could do it using `dplyr`.

But first of all, I think you don't really want to `merge` `values` and `windows`. Based on your description, I think what you want to do is add `windows` as an additional column to `values` (since there is nothing that could be merged, it seems).

So I would first create that additional column in `values`. (I assume here, that `windows` is a vector, although it is not clear from your question, it might also be a data.frame, but you could do it very similar in that case):

```
values$windows <- windows     #assuming windows is a vector
```

Then you can use `dplyr` for the calculation:

#### Method 1:

Referencing each column you want to operate on:

```
library(dplyr)

values %>%
  group_by(windows) %>%
  summarize(Case1 = mean(Case1, na.rm=TRUE),
            Case2 = mean(Case2, na.rm=TRUE),
            Case3 = mean(Case3, na.rm=TRUE),
            Case4 = mean(Case4, na.rm=TRUE))
```

#### Method 2:

Using `summarise_each` to do the same operation for all columns except the grouping variables (windows in this case). If you have a large number of columns you want to do the same operation on, this saves you some typing. Plus, you can specify more functions to be calculated, for example mean and median, if you want.

```
library(dplyr)   # if it's not yet loaded

values %>%
  group_by(windows) %>%
  summarise_each(funs(mean(., na.rm=TRUE)))
```

The result is the same in both cases:

```
#  windows Case1 Case2 Case3 Case4
#1      W1  17.5  21.5  31.0  38.5
#2      W2  33.0  43.5  45.0  73.0
#3      W3  62.0  32.0  72.0  11.0
#4      W4  18.0  49.0  42.5  51.5
#5      W5  45.0  23.0  56.0  74.0
```

#### Edit

Here's an example with much larger sample data including conversion from matrix to data.frame/vector. If your conversion from "big.matrix" to matrix works, then I think, this should work the same way with your original data.

```
# create a matrix with 100 columns and 5 million rows for per column
m <- matrix(runif(100*5e6), ncol=100)

dim(m)
#[1] 5000000     100

object.size(m)
# 4000000200 bytes

# convert to data.frame
df <- as.data.frame(m)

# create a second matrix "windows" with a single column
windows <- matrix(sample(1:1000, nrow(df), replace=TRUE), ncol = 1)

# convert matrix "windows" to vector
windows.vec <- as.vector(windows[,1])

# add windows.vec as a grouping variable to "df"
df$windows <- windows.vec # you could also do this directly from the "windows" matrix

# check dimensions of "df"
dim(df)
#[1] 5000000     101

# now you can do the calculation
df %>%
  group_by(windows) %>%
  summarise_each(funs(mean(., na.rm=T), median(., na.rm=TRUE)))
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but while running `values$windows <- windows` I got `Killed`. How can I solve this?

Comment: Is `windows` a vector or a data.frame? What's its length (if vector) or what's the number of rows and columns (if it's a data.frame) and how many rows and columns does `values` have?

Comment: `dim(values) = 5838178  192`, `values` is `matrix`; windows is `matrix` with `nrow=5838178`

Comment: Oh, ok, I thought we were talking about data.frames. The difficulty with matrices in this case is that they can only store one type of values (e.g.g only numeric, or only characters). And `dplyr` only works with data.frames/data.tables (not matrices). You could try the following before running the code in my answer: `values.df <- as.data.frame(values)` and `windows.vec <- as.vector(windows)` and then use thos objects inside my code. Does that work?

Comment: By the way, how are those two objects created? Maybe it would be the best to directly create them as data.frames in the first place to avoid conversion.

Comment: It works and gives wanted result only for the sample of `values`. If I run it only on `20` columns it works, but when I tried to run it on whole `values.df` it got `killed`. This is why I was thinking about looping.

Comment: Creating `values.df`: `library(bigmemory)`, `load(data.Rdata)`,`class(data) "list"`, `class(data$values) "big.matrix"`,`values <- as.matrix(data$values)`,`values.df <- as.data.frame(values)`. I can't `values.df <- as.data.frame(data$values)` as I got `cannot coerce class "structure("big.matrix", package = "bigmemory")" to a data.frame`.

Comment: If I understand you correct, then `values <- as.matrix(data$values),values.df <- as.data.frame(values)` works fine, right? Did you check the structure of `values.df` afterwards? Are all columns `numeric`? Check `str(values.df)`

Comment: I edited my question. Tell me if there is more information you need.

Comment: I added an example with large data and conversion. Not sure if it helps, but you could try doing it the same way. I'm not familiar with the `bigmemory` package, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

This is by no means the most elegant solution, but it seems to do what you want simply by stacking your `values` data into a single column and then using a tapply() function. It also prevents the need to bind together your `windows` factors and `values` data.

First, a small sample dataset, similar to the above format:

```
> set.seed(42)

> values <- data.frame(replicate(4, sample(1:100, 1e3, replace=T)))

> head(values)
         [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]   85   34   42   77
[2,]   21    3   72   66
[3,]   36   45   77   14
[4,]   78   50    7   31
[5,]   51   89   42   92
[6,]   61   23   55    2

> windows <- rep(1:(1e3/2), each=2)

> head(windows)
[1] 1 1 2 2 3 3
```

Now stack the `values` data into a single column, creating a new variable `ind`:

```
> values <- stack(values)
```

And repeat your windows values to match the length of the stacked dataframe:

```
> windows <- rep(windows, 4)
```

Now you can use a simple `tapply` to calculate the mean by `windows` variable for each column:

```
> tapply(values$values, list(values$ind, windows), mean)
```

Sample output:

```
      1    2    3  ...
X1 50.0 81.5 39.5
X2 36.0 26.5 52.5
X3 68.5 77.5 85.5
X4 52.0 90.0 91.5
```